# string text in textbox to parameter C#

Tags: c#

I have a button and textbox:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param = textBox1.Text;
    string query = string.Format("{0}{1}%'","SELECT <<my_query>>",param);
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Select(query);
}
```

and I have another string:
`string lol = "test";`

I want that what I write in `textbox1 (param)`, it was also in my `string lol`.

Comment: *Where* is this `string lol`? *When* do you want the text to be in this string? What are you trying to do (broader picture)?

Comment: It's unclear! 1rst are you able to excecute a querry and retireve the result? 2nd have you heard of parametrise query? 3rd Have you ever heard the word "Linq" or "Orm"?

Comment: You probably want to use `data binding`. You can bind the value of your text box to your string property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: You want to add `param` to `lol` value? or pass `lol` along with `param`?

Comment: It looks like you want to build user-supplied values into a SQL query. Please do NOT do that (look up SQL injection). Use parameters to pass values to a query.

Comment: I think the lol and param thing are just us focusing on the only intelligible sentence of the question. but if you look at the code it's look like he try to create a `like '%{MyTextBox}%'` sql query

Comment: What is the actual _question?_ What doesn't work? I do immediately see a single unmatched single quote in that format string.

Answer (score 0):

If the `lol` string is declared outside the click event, then it will need to be accessible, i.e. global.

If that is done, then it is as simple as:

```
lol = param
```